# Defining a one-to-one-or-zero relationship in Entity Framework with Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4.3

I know there are a lot of questions around on this subject, but I've not managed to find one that actually explains how to solve my particular problem. Which I suppose means that it might be insoluble (I think it might be 'backwards' to EF's way of thinking), but I have to ask.

I have a model with three (abbreviated) POCOs as so:

```
[Table("People")]
public class Person {
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}

public class Location {
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public int LocationTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual LocationType LocationType { get; set; }
}

public class Van : Location {
    public int PartyID { get; set; }
    public virtual Party Party { get; set; }
}
```

These are backed by (abbreviated) database tables (we write these by hand):

```
CREATE TABLE People (
    PersonID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    PersonName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PersonID)
)

CREATE TABLE Locations (
    LocationID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    LocationTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (LocationTypeID) REFERENCES LocationTypes(LocationTypeID)
)

CREATE TABLE Vans (
    LocationID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PersonID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (LocationID),
    FOREIGN KEY (LocationID) REFERENCES Locations(LocationID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES People(PersonID)
)
```

You can probably imagine what `LocationTypes` looks like.

`Locations` is the root of a table-per-type hierarchy - there are also check constraints in place to enforce this. `Vans` are a kind of location, as are other things irrelevant here like `Warehouse`.

Now, a `Van` belongs to a `Person`, in that we issue a van to an employee and it's their responsibility to fill it up with fuel, not crash it, take it to customer sites and order more stuff when they've used up all their supply of screws, drill bits and armoured DC cable. However, not every `Person` has a van (some of them work in pairs in one van), and the `Person` table doesn't have a foreign key which points to the `Van` - it's the other way around. This is in some sense a historical accident, but it models the situation quite neatly because while a `Person` doesn't have to have a `Van`, a `Van` most assuredly has to have a person.

So to my question: how do I get `Person` to have a navigation property with their `Van` in it?

```
public virtual Van Van { get; set; }
```

I've done a lot of playing around with data annotations and the fluent API, and the closest I've got is this in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Van>()
    .HasRequired(v => v.Person)
    .WithOptional(p => p.Van);
```

Unfortunately this tries to populate the `Van` property with a proxy that yields a `Location` object. It might even be the right `Location` object (I haven't been able to check), but it's not realised that it should be looking for vans. I do suspect, however, that it might be trying to match `PersonID` against `LocationID` when it does the lookup - without the Fluent API mapping, I just get no vans at all, which is what I'd expect (all `PersonID` values are lower than the lowest `LocationID` values which correspond to vans so couldn't possibly find anything).

This would no doubt be quite easy if `Person` had a nullable foreign key to `Van`, but then we'd have foreign keys in both directions, and if we took the one out of `Van` then we'd not be modelling the absolutely essential constraint that a `Van` has a `Person`.

So, I suppose, `Van` owns this relationship, and the `Van` property on `Person` is an inverse navigation property, but it seems EF isn't very good at this kind of trick with one-to-ones even if one end is optional. Is there a way to make it work, or do I have to accept a compromise?

We generally refuse to compromise the database model for the sake of Entity Framework's missing features. What I really need is a way to tell EF that the `Van` property on `Person` can be populated by joining to Vans on Vans.PersonID = Person.PersonID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this is at the moment not supported. You mentioned that you didn't managed to find any question where would be your problem solved. I wonder if you find any question mentioning that EF doesn't support unique constraints / candidate key which is absolutely necessary to solve this type of one-to-one relations.

In database one-to-one relation can be achieved only if FK in dependent table is unique. This can be done by two ways: placing unique constraint (index) on FK column in dependent table or using PK in dependent table as FK to principal table.

EF enforces same rules for referential integrity as database but in case of one-to-one relationships and lack of support for unique constraint it doesn't support the former way. EF can model one-to-one relationship only by using  PK of dependent table as FK to principal table.

You can vote for support of Unique constraints / candidate keys on [Data UserVoice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support).

How to solve  your particular issue? By cheating EF. Let EF think that you have one-to-many relation and place unique constraint on `PersonID` in `Van` table. Than update your Person like this:

```
[Table("People")]
public class Person {
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Van> Vans { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Van Van 
    {
        get { return Vans.FirstOrDefault(); }
        set
        {
             Vans.Clear();
             if (value != null)
             {
                 Vans.Add(value);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

It is pretty ugly workaround because `Vans` collection is still public. You can play with its visibility but make sure you understand few things:

- Once `Vans` is not public you must map it in `OnModelCreating` and for that context must be able to see the property or you must provide mapping configuration which does that. Check [this](http://blog.cincura.net/232731-mapping-private-protected-properties-in-entity-framework-4-x-code-first/) and [this](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/26/code-first-data-annotations-on-non-public-properties/) for some more information.
- `Vans` property must not break rules for proxy creation to support lazy loading
- Eager loading must use `Vans` property

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case, but this is ultimately the solution I implemented after posting the question just so we could get it working. At least the database knows what's going on!